# Deploying to linode via capistrano using git on a windows machine

Tags: git, windows-7, capistrano

I am trying to deploy via capistrano and git on a windows machine without much success. I run into the 'Too many arguments error'. Someone else had a similar problem and posted a [solution in 2010](http://lifeisrails.wordpress.com/2010/03/25/capistrano-deploy_via-copy-from-gitwindows/) but this fix is not working for me. It is set to deploy from local machine through "set :deploy_via, :copy".

Here is the detailed error message:

```
$ cap staging deploy
   triggering load callbacks
 * executing `staging'
   triggering start callbacks for `deploy'
 * executing `multistage:ensure'
 * executing `uploads:register_dirs'
 * executing `deploy'
 * executing `deploy:update'
** transaction: start
 * executing `deploy:update_code'
   executing locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:username/_app.git deve lopment"
   command finished in 2408ms
 * getting (via checkout) revision 121e566c349a1406cba1936abeda49109de7fd78 to C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Temp/20120329203009
   executing locally: git clone git@github.com:user/_app.git C:/Users/ username/AppData/Local/Temp/20120329203009 && cd C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/ 20120329203009 && git checkout -b deploy 121e566c349a1406cba1936abeda49109de7fd7
   8 Too many arguments.
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what version of capistrano are you using, it looks like the `set :deploy_via, :copy` is broken - the && are treated as params to command instead of a bash control operator

Comment: Not much help but I too have the same problem. Everything works fine until it tries to clone/cd/checkout with a chained command. I also tried the fix but to no avail. Windows 7 / GitBash 1.7 / Cap 2.12.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm in the same case.

What I've found is that my Windows 7 64 bits is recognized as a different RUBY_PLATFORM than the planned case.
Mine is the 'i386-mingw32' RUBY_PLATFORM.

If you read the 'base.rb' around line 53, there is the condition

```
if 'RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /win32/'
```

So, in my case, it don't succeed. I change the line like it :

```
if 'RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /win32/' || RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /i386-mingw32/
```

And it's fine.

I've kept the code written by Railsblogger. (with an update for displaying execution time)

So, now, it's like that :

```
      # A wrapper for Kernel#system that logs the command being executed.
      def system(*args)
        cmd = args.join(' ')
        result = nil
        if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /win32/ || RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /i386-mingw32/
          cmd = cmd.split(/\s+/).collect {|w| w.match(/^[\w+]+:\/\//) ? w : w.gsub('/', '\\') }.join(' ') # Split command by spaces, change / by \\ unless element is a some+thing://

          # code from http://lifeisrails.wordpress.com/2010/03/25/capistrano-deploy_via-copy-from-gitwindows/
          if cmd =~ /\s&&\s/ && cmd =~ /^git\s+clone/
            cmd1, cmd = cmd.split(" && ", 2)
            logger.trace "executing locally: #{cmd1}"
            elapsed = Benchmark.realtime do
                result = super(cmd1)
            end
            logger.trace "command finished in #{(elapsed * 1000).round}ms"
            result
          end

          cmd.gsub!(/^cd /,'cd /D ') # Replace cd with cd /D
          cmd.gsub!(/&& cd /,'&& cd /D ') # Replace cd with cd /D
          logger.trace "executing locally: #{cmd}"
          elapsed = Benchmark.realtime do
            result = super(cmd)
          end
        else
          logger.trace "executing locally: #{cmd}"
          elapsed = Benchmark.realtime do
            result = super
          end
        end
```

Hope it will help !!

Tell me if it works for you ?

And... if it's not ok, you could test to display your 'RUBY_PLATFORM', by adding a line before the condition like

```
logger.trace RUBY_PLATFORM
```